# Redstone to detect "falling" (self closing trapdoor)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

**Is there a way to get a redstone signal when a player falls through a hole (right after he falls, not when he lands)?**

Background: I created a bubble elevator and want a trapdoor for the other way around. When you want to go down, you open the trapdoor and fall, but the trapdoor would have to be closed again immediately after. I know I could make this work with tripwire, but I lack the space for that at the moment. If there is a better solution, I would be very glad for help.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it (for me personally, question is still not answered with this solution). Instead of hitting the trapdoor directly, I hit the button. Doesn't make much difference and I somehow like this approach even more.

[image]

For other people looking into this issue, I won't accept my own answer. If you come up with a more accurate approach to the question, feel free to post. I will give you credit for it.

Comment: I don't like being downvoted without a reason. :/

Comment: Tip: use an iron trapdoor to make sure you don't accidentally open it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a command block to close the door when they fall put a command block in the hole do

```
/testfor @a[r=3]
```

If this doesn’t work do

```
/testfor @a[radius(maybe distance)=3]
```

put another command block so they make a chain the second one saying

```
/setblock (coordinates of trapdoor) trapdoor (fiddle with numbers here starting with 0)
```

NOT ON SURVIVAL MODE

Answer (score 0):

[Tripwire](https://minecraft.wiki/w/String#Redstone_component) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=String&oldid=1293810#Redstone_component)) is your friend. Just put the string where you'll fall through and the tripwire hooks to the side of it, then get a signal from it to the trapdoor. You don't even need to invert it, since it will close the trapdoor when the signal ends.

Comment: I tried that before and it did not work (at least not without other workarounds). It triggers, but not the door right above you, which is what I wanted. You need to fall through the wire, not the "wire holder", but the "wire holder" triggers the block above it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You have to fall through the string part, not the hook part. Then you just use redstone to lead the signal up into the trapdoor.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a pressure plate, it may be faster and simpler than a button.

Your question, however, needs to be made more clear, for a player can fall through the hole without ever hitting a button or a pressure plate.

Comment: True, but I don't want it to happen "by accident", meaning when you walk back or whatever and just fall down without any intention of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea 
its not the exact solution of what you asked for but it might stoll be helpfull
basicily use an observer that gets triggered when the trapdoor is oppened with a bit of delay (redstone repeaters) and redstone repeater to the block behind the trapdoor to get avtivated wich will Close the trapdoor again
so in this way when you open the trapdoor the observer will get triggered the signla will get delayed then it will Power the block behind the trapdoor wich will Close the trapdoor back
nice basic and easy to build hope it helped you